ASP.NET Core - error 404.15 after conversion from .NET 4.7 to .NET 6.0
I have recently converted all my apps from .NET Frameworks to .NET 6.0. I have having issue with a MVC controller method which attempts to reproduce a result that was historically created in memory, and leaves enough information for it to be re-created later. This data is not stored other than in the history of the request.
When that history is displayed, there is an option to view the result on a chart. That URL is fairly long as it includes everything needed to reproduce a graphic of the result.
Here is the HTTP error message:

HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
Detailed Info:
Detailed Error Information:
Module       RequestFilteringModule
Notification     BeginRequest
Handler      aspNetCore
Error Code       0x00000000

Here is a sample URL:
http://localhost:44397/Home/TradeViewer?tradeId=0&tradeDefId=32121969&accountId=1&trData=%7B%22tempGuid%22%3A%22b678a8b9-cafd-4c86-86f7-a02555e63ead%22%2C%22tradeResponse%22%3Anull%2C%22desiredUnits%22%3A1575778.0%2C%22returnOnCapital%22%3A0.0168080932588314%2C%22returnOnRisk%22%3A0.6723240020109068%2C%22TotalProfitLossEquityNet%22%3A16073.888623876659%2C%22tradeDirectionOverride%22%3Anull%2C%22equityNumberCumulativeAmount%22%3Anull%2C%22IsReversedTrade%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsAlteredTrade%22%3Atrue%2C%22reprocessedInCSharpProcessor%22%3Afalse%2C%22savedCSharpValues%22%3Anull%2C%22firstEntryBar%22%3Anull%2C%22lastCloseBar%22%3Anull%2C%22marginRequirementAtFill%22%3A46620.16259982686%2C%22marginRequirementAdditional%22%3Anull%2C%22cashValue%22%3A1165067.1608543706%2C%22TotalFinancingCharges%22%3A0.0%2C%22TotalBrokerCommissions%22%3A0.0%2C%22TradeResultId%22%3A0%2C%22AccountId%22%3A1%2C%22TradeDefinitionId%22%3A32121969%2C%22DateProcessed%22%3A%222024-09-20T11%3A24%3A28.2852507-04%3A00%22%2C%22TotalProfitLossInPips%22%3A95.800000000%2C%22TotalRiskInPips%22%3A143.700000000%2C%22TotalRewardInPips%22%3A95.800000000%2C%22FirstEntryDate%22%3A%222020-06-22T18%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22CloseDate%22%3A%222020-07-10T10%3A59%3A59.999%22%2C%22CloseReason%22%3A%22LIMIT%22%2C%22CancellationDate%22%3Anull%2C%22CancellationReason%22%3Anull%2C%22TotalProfitLossInPipsAtLimit%22%3Anull%2C%22TotalProfitLossInPipsAtMax%22%3Anull%2C%22TotalProfitLossInPipsAtMin%22%3Anull%2C%22Verified%22%3Anull%2C%22VerifiedFailedReason%22%3Anull%2C%22MustBeAuthorizedByDate%22%3Anull%2C%22DateAuthorizedByUser%22%3Anull%2C%22DateAdded%22%3A%222024-09-20T11%3A24%3A28.2852507-04%3A00%22%2C%22TotalProfitLossEquity%22%3A16073.888623876659%2C%22AccountBalanceAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22AccountBalanceAtExit%22%3A995250.7597023413%2C%22AccountBalanceBeforeExit%22%3A979176.8710784647%2C%22MarginRequirement%22%3A46620.65482541996%2C%22AvailableMarginAtEntry%22%3A397121.1948907204%2C%22AvailableMarginAtExit%22%3Anull%2C%22UsableAccountValue%22%3A338139.19232702616%2C%22SkippedDueToMarginRequirement%22%3Afalse%2C%22LotType%22%3A%22Unit%22%2C%22LotCount%22%3A1575778.0%2C%22Units%22%3A1575778.0%2C%22ConversionRateUnitsAtClose%22%3Anull%2C%22CopiedFromTradeResultId%22%3Anull%2C%22ApiTradeId%22%3Anull%2C%22ApiTransactionId%22%3Anull%2C%22StopLossPriceOverride%22%3Anull%2C%22ExceptionDetails%22%3Anull%2C%22FirstEntryPrice%22%3A0.70054%2C%22LastClosePrice%22%3A0.69096%2C%22ConversionRateUnitsAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22ConversionRateMarginAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22ApiStopLossOrderId%22%3Anull%2C%22ApiTakeTrailingStopLossOrderId%22%3Anull%2C%22ApiTakeProfitOrderId%22%3Anull%2C%22CommissionAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22FinancingAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22GuaranteedExecutionFeeAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22HalfSpreadCostAtEntry%22%3Anull%2C%22CommissionAtExit%22%3Anull%2C%22FinancingAtExit%22%3Anull%2C%22GuaranteedExecutionFeeAtExit%22%3Anull%2C%22HalfSpreadCostAtExit%22%3Anull%2C%22DirectionalBiasRuntimeDataId%22%3Anull%2C%22DirectionalBiasBetAlgorithmIndex%22%3A301%2C%22DirectionalBiasValue%22%3A%22Bearish%22%2C%22TrailingStopActivationPrice%22%3Anull%2C%22TrailingStopTrailingAmountInDecimal%22%3Anull%2C%22TrailingStopIgnoreLimit%22%3Anull%2C%22UpdatedPriceStopLoss%22%3Anull%2C%22UpdatedPriceTakeProfit%22%3Anull%2C%22UpdatedPriceTrailingStopLoss%22%3Anull%2C%22UpdatedByAccountUpdate%22%3Anull%2C%22AccountTradeSettingId%22%3A0%2C%22ActionOverride%22%3Anull%2C%22StopOverride%22%3A0.71491%2C%22LimitOverride%22%3A0.69096%2C%22CloseByDate%22%3A%222020-09-21T17%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22EnterByDate%22%3A%222020-06-25T05%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22TotalRiskEquity%22%3A23907.95%2C%22FinancingOnTrade%22%3Anull%2C%22AccountBalanceAtCreate%22%3A956318.386407752%2C%22UnrealizedProfitLoss%22%3Anull%2C%22LastUpdateDate%22%3Anull%2C%22Account%22%3Anull%2C%22Positions%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22TradeDefinition%22%3Anull%2C%22AccountTradeSetting%22%3Anull%7D
I have spent nearly a full day searching for an answer, and many answers say to change the web.config.  I did that (for IIS Express) and that does NOT change the result.
I have also seen answers which indicate to use the  [RequestSizeLimit(16384)] attribute on the Controller Method.  That also does not change the result.
I have also seen some answers on how to configure the length for Kestrel, but I am not using Kestrel.  I tried this (even though not using Kestrel) and of course it also did not work.
Does anyone know how to configure the length of the query string, on ASP.NET Core MVC?
Does anyone know how to disable or configure the 'RequestFilteringModule' ?
I tried changing the web.config for IIS Express.
I tried adding the Request Size Limit attribute to the controller method.
I tried configuring Kestrel in the app startup.
None of these changed the result.
So... I was asked to provides steps to reproduce this issue.  Here are those steps:

Create a new Project and select the ASP.NET Core MVC project template

Open the index view Views/Index.cshtml. Add a link <a hRef = "very long URI">Very Long Query String</a>

Change the configuration to 'IIS Express' and run the app.

Click the link added to Index.  The error will appear.


Now, while I was reproducing this issue, I found the there was not issue unless I used the 'IIS Express' configuration.  If I used the configuration named after the created project, then I DID NOT GET the error.  This was an obvious clue that the issue was in IIS and not in the code/project per say.
From this observation, I found the solution.  I added the following to the applicationhost.config file [located in $SOLUTION_FOLDER/.vs/$PROJECT_NAME/config/applicationhost.config].
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" maxQueryString="16384" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

The key change here is the maxQueryString value.  I changed this value to 16K and the issue was resolved. 



This question is similar to: How to configure the web.config to allow requests of any length. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Even this issue has been solved, I still don't suggest you put so long data inside the url, I suggest you put it inside the request body and use post method to avoid request missed.

The referenced question did have what turned out to the be same solution.  However, that question was 12 years old, and I believed my issue to be related to .Net Core (.Net 6.0).  The new information is that if you are using IIS Express then the solution is indeed the same as it was 12 years ago.  If you are not using IIS Express, and are in .Net 6.0 or greater, then the issue does not present itself.

Using a POST is in fact, not an option.  This link is embedded in a very large document and clicking the link, re-creates an image of the object.  POST cannot be used with an , and there is no form which would be required to use POST.  What I did do to make the query string shorter, is I ZIPed the query string, then used base 64 encoding.  That reduced the size of the string by about 65% on average.  Note that this was not required as the indicated solution did work with the longer query string length.
